# Suppressing javascript lint error

Tags: javascript, lint

I'm developing a Firefox extension and I'd like to use Javascript Lint to help me find bugs. However, I keep on getting a "SyntaxError: missing name after . operator" error for the second line:

```
const Cu = Components.utils;
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
```

Apparently it's because "import" is a keyword. But it's used like that in Mozilla... A similar problem is with the "let" keyword.

Anyone knows how to ignore those errors?

Comment: you might be able to go `Cu['import']("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");` although that is kind of messy I guess

Comment: +1 for cryo's comment because `cursor['continue']()` works to replace `cursor.continue()` with `IndexedDB`. Not too messy ; )

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to disable this particular warning, but if you send a message to the [Yahoo Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/), outlining your requirements, you may be able to persuade Douglas Crockford to include this as an option in a future release.

Alternatively, if you have downloaded a version of JSLint, rather than using http://www.jslint.com/, you could try removing the line:

```
reserve('import');
```

Comment: I was afraid that I will get an answer like that. :-) But thanks anyway!